# Why do i get this error in Webpack 5.11.0: 1 ERROR in child compilations?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

so i get this error in my webpack code when trying to compile it, this happens when i start in production mode and when i delete html-loader the error is gone, i also include HtmlWebpackPlugin and file-loader to use :

webpack.prod.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    publicPath: '',
    filename: "js/[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ]
});
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/index.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/html/index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'imgs'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  }
}
```

Do someone can help me? I will stay aware if anyone needs any type of information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest you check the path to the html file. This usually happens if the path is wrong

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, thanks! Whoever finds this problem please check twice all your paths from the HTML and JS.

Comment: Saved my day. I was searching for this solution from past 4 hours. And it was a silly mistake. Can't we ignore the broken links in html-loader directly?